# Changing Frame Programmatically iOS 7?

Tags: objective-c, uiview, nstextfield, cgrect, ios7

BEFORE READING "iOS 7 OMG DOWNVOTE"

> The problem has been solved and is not related to iOS 7 at all.  The problem was that with autolayout turned on, you cannot change the frame directly but must edit constraints instead.

So I have an app that is in the App Store and I you type in some `UITextField`s but some of the text fields were covered by the keyboard so I programmatically moved them up.  Now I am working with the Xcode and iOS 7 betas and this functionality stopped working.  Here is my code:

```
-(void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField{
    textFieldRect = textField.frame;
    textField.frame = CGRectMake(5, 80, self.view.frame.size.width-10, 31);
}
-(void)textFieldDidEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField{
    textField.frame = textFieldRect;
}
```

I check with an `NSLog` for the width of `textFieldRect` and `TextField.frame` at the end of `textFieldDidBeginEditing:` and the values are different (as they should be), yet there is no visual change.  I know there are other ways to protect the textField from the keyboard, but I would really prefer to get this working as I hope to animate it, and I know that there is no reason this would not be possible.

Comment: It's under NDA so you should use the forums on apple's developer site.

Comment: I love this "this is under NDA, let's downvote it" attitude...

Comment: @H2CO3 I agree it's stupid to cite an NDA as the reason for a close vote or a down vote, it's equally misguided to post a question about an unfinished SDK on an unfinished OS.

Comment: Why is there an ios7 tag if iOS 7 questions are not allowed?

Comment: And its not like `UITextField`s are some sort of new thing that your not supposed to talk about yet...

Comment: @CodaFi no, see http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/180573/183887

Comment: Regarding how to handle code under NDA see http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/94465/183887

Comment: @WolfLink UITextField isn't new, but your problems running your code on the *new OS* are.

Comment: Got answer to this question on the Apple Dev Forums.  Turns out it wasn't really related to iOS 7; the problem was that autolayout prevents the frame from changing programmatically like that.